Since when did Arqade require registration to post questions and answers, and why was it required?
While browsing through a Meta Stack Exchange post about unregistered users not being allowed to post questions on some SE sites, at the time of writing, I noticed that Arqade wasn't listed among those requiring registration. However, upon testing in a private browser window, I confirmed that Arqade does, in fact, require registration to ask or answer questions.
Intrigued by this discrepancy, I searched for "registration" on Arqade Meta and stumbled upon an old post from July 2012: Do one-rep unregistered users contribute positively to Arqade? This post and its answers mention that unregistered users were able to ask or answer questions on Arqade.
It seems that at some point between July 2012 and now, Arqade has changed its policy and implemented a registration requirement for asking or answering questions. This got me curious about a couple of things:

When exactly did this change take place?
What were the reasons behind implementing this registration requirement?
Who implemented this policy change on behalf of the Arqade community?


After some work with SEDE, I can say with fairly high confidence that the most recent (undeleted) post by an unregistered user occurred on 2022-02-26. Not sure what changed.

I've slapped the [tag:status-review] tag on this, and I also reached out to the CM team directly, so hopefully we'll get an official answer to this soon.

@Wipqozn soon can be long months, yeah. Anyway, my best guess is some spam wave from unregistered users, which was escalated to the CM team, and as result they imposed the requirement to register account.

@ShadowWizard I'll poke the CM team again.

This change was implemented on February 26, 2022 by Stack Exchange, and it was implemented to combat a network wide series of spam accounts.
It was supposed to be temporary, but looks like reversing it was forgotten about. The mod team was notified about this, but we'd forgotten about it by the time this post was made.
The mod team will reach out to the CM team to see if we can re-enable unregistered posting. If the answer is yes, we'll make a separate post getting community input on if we actually want to re-enable it.
